# How to create a puzzle game like Sokoban or Mummy Maze

Tags: maze

I'm a beginner game developers, I'm really like puzzle game like Sokoban, Mummy Maze or Chip's Challenge. If i want to create a game like that (a simple game but player have to think to solve it) where should i start, what should i read to get ideas or game algorithm, ... anything can help me build a game like that.

Here's some picture about these games

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XHdf.png

http://tientrieu.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/MmMaze5.jpg

Please help me, thanks for your time.
Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using [PuzzleScript](http://www.puzzlescript.net/) to start a project like this. It's a simple environment for building tile-based games that have very little object state. Even if you end up using something else in the end, it's good for prototyping rules and levels.

Comment: Thanks for your suggest, i am trying puzzlescript.